# Unity - blur only selected layers

Tags: unity, post-processing, image-effects

I'm messing around with Unity 2017's post processing tools while making a 2D game that benefits from the parallaxing effect using a perspective camera. 
Please note that the game is mostly made using *sprites*.

Now, I have a **playerGround**, a **backGround** and a **foreGround**. I wish to blur the background and foreground only but not the playerground. 
I'd like to know how to do this as playing with the focal length didn't do anything, everything receives the same blur amount regardless of the distance from camera.

Comment: Indeed it was a sort of duplicate of my other question, just asked out of despair. Thanks for garbage collecting the forums :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use one camera for the layers you'd like to blur, apply post process to that one, and another camera for the unblurred layers. Parent one to the other camera, only move the parent, and set the camera depth to match.

Comment: That would work if I have no blurred foreground (in fact I did just that first). If I have a blurred FG, it blurs everything unfortunately.